# C# how to find item which item is clicked in a list?

Tags: c#, list, if-statement, find

I am trying to check on which item i have clicked, i am making a kind of inventory, that if you clicked on 1W, that texture will change to the clicked texture.
This is the list i have made.
But i can't seem to find a code that works.

```
this.drivers = new List<Driver>()
                {
                    new Driver(this.game, this, new Vector2 (0, 62), "1W", "Images/Clubs/Drivers/1W", this.inventory),
                    new Driver(this.game, this, new Vector2 (62, 62), "2W", "Images/Clubs/Drivers/2W", this.inventory),
                    new Driver(this.game, this, new Vector2 (124, 62), "3W", "Images/Clubs/Drivers/3W", this.inventory),
                    new Driver(this.game, this, new Vector2 (186, 62), "4W", "Images/Clubs/Drivers/4W", this.inventory),
                    new Driver(this.game, this, new Vector2 (248, 62), "5W", "Images/Clubs/Drivers/5W", this.inventory),
                    new Driver(this.game, this, new Vector2 (310, 62), "6W", "Images/Clubs/Drivers/6W", this.inventory),
                    new Driver(this.game, this, new Vector2 (0, 124), "7W", "Images/Clubs/Drivers/7W", this.inventory)
                };
```

I know i can find it to check the name with :

```
If ( name == "1W")
{
   //Do Something
}
```

but that will mean, if i want to check all 7 i will get 7 if statements, and i have like 3 of this lists, so that will be like 21 if statements.

I know it is possible in 1 sentence per list but i can't remember the code!

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: You're looking for a loop or LINQ.

Comment: Do you have to do similar things with every value?

Comment: @SLaks i was indeed thinking of a loop, but not sure how to check which item i clicked on.

Comment: @shaharyar, yes i have to do the same with every value, every value has to change it's image, nothing else :)

Comment: why don't you use `selectedindexchanged` event of listbox?

Comment: @Shaharyar: from the code it looks like he is using XNA, not WinForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using LINQ:

```
this.drivers.Where(d => d.Name == name).ToList().ForEach(delegate(Driver d)
{
    // Do something
});
```

If the names are unique, this will be easier to use:

```
var driver = this.drivers.Single(d => d.Name == name);
// Do something with driver
```

Alternatively, you can use a loop:

```
foreach(var d in this.drivers)
{
    if(d.Name == name)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

If your items will *always* be ordered `"1W","2W",...`, those will help you identify the index:

```
var index = int.Parse(name[0].ToString()) - 1; // e.g. "3W"[0].ToString() = "3"
var driver = this.drivers[index];
// Do something
```

Comment: With the alternative, i will still get more than 1 if statement? i guess.

can't i get the index of the name out of the list, because 1W = in the list, index 0, and 2W is in the list index 1.

and how do i use the LINQ? i didn't get that one and looked it up many times.

Comment: I can't figure it out, it musn't be this hard.
The error is, can't convert a string to an int, and name isn't an array, name is what comes out of the list, it is just an variable.

Comment: @JpHouten: The conversion error was my mistake, sorry. use `int.Parse` instead of the cast `(int)`.
For what you said about `name` not being an array: I think you are wondering why I am using the `[0]` indexer. If you use this on a string, `[i]` will give you the i-th character, that is, for instance `"abcde"[2] == 'c'`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create `selectedindexchanged` event of `listbox`:

```
this.listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var SelectedObject = this.drivers[listbox1.SelectedIndex];
    //now you can simply use it SelectedObject.Path or SelectedObject.Name or what ever property names you have
}
```